# How to Update UILabel from Another ViewController

Tags: ios

I'm using Storyboards and iOS 6.1, I'm initiating a view like this:

```
PropertiesViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Properties"];
```

`PropertiesViewController` has a 60px height viewn an including some labels and more. I want to add these views to another `ScrollView` as subview. Here what I'm doing:

```
controller.leftLabel.text = @"Test";
controller.background.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"someimage.png"];
controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, currentHeight, controller.view.frame.size.width, cellHeight);
[self.scrollView addSubview: controller.view];
```

leftLabel is a `UILabel` and backgorund is a `UIImageView`.The problem is none of view's elements are not updating outside of `PropertiesViewController`. `addSubview:` is just adding as how its created, not allow to configure.

I've already checked `NSNotificationCenter` approach, if I'm not wrong it's not about updating instances. And I've also already added a method to receiver class to update labels inside of `PropertiesViewController`. That even did not worked.

What am I doing wrong?

**Note**: You may ask that why just I'm not using a `TableView`. There has to be more dynamic resources and their besides are not clear. There is also one thing that TableView is not possible with ScrollView, in some cases I've never use a TableView so scrollview will manage scroll.

Any help would be great.

**EDIT:**

According to Kalpesh's answer here what I did:

In my sender view controller:

```
PropertiesViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Properties"]; 
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"update" object:@"Test string"];

controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, currentHeight, controller.view.frame.size.width, cellHeight);
 // not sure how but I can change frame successfully.
[self.scrollView addSubview: controller.view];
```

Here is receiver:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"Called"); // Working fine

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(changetext:) name:@"update" object:nil]; 

     //even if set some object, nothing changed
}

- (void) changetext:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"Received"); // Not working
   leftLabel.text = [notification object];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, You have to send notification from other viewcontroller when you want to change label of text
 ..

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"changetext"        object:stringobj];
```

in mainviewcontroller

```
  -(void)viewDidLoad

{
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self    selector:@selector(changetext:) name:@"changetext" object:nil];

}

- (void) changetext:(NSNotification *)notification
{
   NSString * text =[notification object];
     lbl.text=text;

 }
```

Comment: and also do this in dealloc `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];`

Comment: Thanks but couldnt receive notification even if I've added a log line. No error no warning, but still couldnt update. I'm using postNotificationName method instead of assingnin text, is that true?

Comment: YES, you can use postNotification and it will be definitely work. I have  implement same thing in my app. can you tell me changetext method should be called or not. put breakpoint and check it .

Comment: I've updated my answer, added what I did, also there is one point, We've added a breakpoint (my friend also commented) not called. Please can you check and tell us any help?

Comment: here is sample code, https://www.dropbox.com/s/rd6ll7zvgagh30t/UpdateLABELFROMSECONDVIEWCONTROLLER.zip